# Where can I find the SAP configuration properties?

Tags: sap-erp

I need to know which status should I choose to release a PM order, to create a quotation after. Is there a place where I can find something like this :

- For the order type `ZCS9` the right release status is `OKDE`
- For the order type `ZCS3` the right release status is `VALD`

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statuses of PM orders consist of *System statuses* and *User statuses*. System statuses cannot be changed by user and are used by system for determining available business transaction for certain object type. Usual system status assigned before release is `REL`.
The functional scope of the user status depends on your settings in Customizing. General process for customizing user statuses for release strategy is following:

1. Go to *SPRO -> Plant Maintenance and Customer Service ->Maintenance and Service Processing -> Maintenance and Service Orders -> General Data -> User status for Orders -> Define status profiles* and  select option *Assign User Status to Order Types*
2. There you can discover which status profile is assigned to target order type
3. Then go to *Define User Status Profile for Orders* and select status profile discovered on previous step.
4. On profile page you can observe and adjust all statuses which were set up for this order type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SAP System to check the exact path, but look in *SPRO->Plant Maitenance and Customer Service -> Maitenance and Services Processing -> Functions and setting for order*. 
There must be an option in this sumbenu.